# Javascript JSON.parse a string comming from python with an apostrophe

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a python string:

```
x = [{"value": "Sek'Kuar"}, ...]
y = json.dumps(x)
```

Then, how can I `JSON.parse` `y`?

The appostrophe is giving me trouble.

Comment: that's not a string, that's an object

Comment: @JaromandaX `json.dumps` serializes it.

Comment: oh, that's python code in the question ... my mistake ... how is `y` getting from python to javascript?

Comment: working fine for me in [JS](https://jsfiddle.net/vLL6emuk/)

Comment: @HishamKaram $10 says he's got it in a single-quoted string that's being broken by the apostrophe... which you seemingly know since you escaped it with a backslash in your fiddle...

Comment: @JaredSmith `json.dumps` produce `>>> x = [{"value": "Sek'Kuar"},]
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(x)
'[{"value": "Sek\'Kuar"}]'`

Comment: @alejoss what's the error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: `The appostrophe is giving me trouble.` what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `json.dumps()`, it convert's your python object to valid `JSON` format. For example in your case:

```
>>> import json
>>> x = [{"value": "Sek'Kuar"}]
>>> json.dumps(x)
'[{"value": "Sek\'Kuar"}]'
```

`'` is replaced by `\'` which is valid JSON.

If you are getting some error in your code, it is not because your JSON format is wrong (to be specific, `'` is not troubling you).

You may check on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2dvkarj/1/) that it is working without any error.